# How to make "tri-directional" scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape a business directory with Scrapy and Python 3.

You know the concept of "bi-directional" scraping:

- 1st direction => Scraping the urls of details page of item (detail page of Business A, detail page of business B, etc....) which are displayed on 1 page of result.
- 2nd direction => Scraping the urls of pagination of resuls pages (page 1, page 2, page 3, etc...)

I guess you understand this stuff.

The website business directory I want to **scrape** has a 3rd "direction". All the businesses I want to **scrape** in this website are organised by ALPHABET.

I need to click on an ALPHABET letter to get thousands of businesses displayed on several pages pagination (please see pictures attached for better understanding).

[image]

So I added the alphabet urls by hand in the start_urls. But it didn't work. Have a look at my code:

```
class AnnuaireEntreprisesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    #here I added the list of ALPHABET pages which containes several pages of results per letter
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/entreprises-0-9.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-a.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-b.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-c.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-d.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-e.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-f.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-g.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-h.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-i.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-j.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-k.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-l.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-m.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-n.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-o.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-p.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-q.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-r.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-s.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-t.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-u.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-v.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-w.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-x.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-y.html',
                  'http://www.example.com/entreprises-z.html'
                  ]




    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a[@class='btn-fiche dcL ']/@href").extract()

        for url in urls:
            #here I scrape the urls of detail page of business
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url)
            print('Voici absolute url :' + absolute_url)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_startup)

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='nextPages']/@href").get() or ''
        if next_page:
            #Here I scrape the pagination urls
            absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            print('Voici absolute url NEXT PAGE :' + absolute_next_page)
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_startup(self, response):
        print("Parse_startup details!!!")
        #and here I scrape the details of the business
```

I am a beginner who started to learn Scrapy a few weeks ago.

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what problem did you have specifically? Did you debug the code and find the point at which it failed?

Comment: I just saw spider scraping url but my a

Comment: Are you sure you need trailing whitespace here `"//a[@class='btn-fiche dcL ']/@href"`?

Comment: you should read more about concurrent requests,it will answer your question

Comment: You should get the URLs off the page and not hard code them if possible

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap